# Minumum value from compare of two arrays on each elements in c#

Tags: c#

I have below which is working for the 1st element...I just can't figure out how to do it for all elements on the arrays... thanks in advance

```
        int[] ListNumb1 = new int[] { 2, 4, 6 };
        int[] ListNumb2 = new int[] { 3, 1, 9 };


        if (ListNumb1[0] < ListNumb2[0])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ListNumb1[0]);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine(ListNumb2[0]);




        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: put it inside a loop :D

Comment: Do you want to return an array of minimum values, or just output them?

Comment: hi yes I would like it to be return it in an array. thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8) method to *zip* the 2 collections (arrays) together, and [`Math.Min`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.min?view=netframework-4.8) to get the lowest value.

```
var result = ListNumb1.Zip(ListNumb2, Math.Min)
```

**Full Example**

```
int[] ListNumb1 = new int[] { 2, 4, 6 };
int[] ListNumb2 = new int[] { 3, 1, 9 };

// Result will be an IEnumerbale<int>
var result = ListNumb1.Zip(ListNumb2, Math.Min)

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result));
```

**Output**

```
2,1,6
```

<sub>***Note*** : To get the output in an array, just Call `ListNumb1.Zip(ListNumb2, Math.Min).ToArray()`</sub>

---

Or you could use a classic *for loop*

```
// Allocate the array
var results = new int[ListNumb1.Length];

// Iterate over each element in both arrays
for (var i = 0; i < ListNumb1.Length; i++)
   results[i] = Math.Min(ListNumb1[i], ListNumb2[i]);
```

<sub>***Note 2*** : Both these examples assume the arrays are of equal length, if that is not that case, you will need to validate and act accordingly</sub>

---

**Additional resources**

- [Enumerable.Zip Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8)

  > Applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two
  >   sequences, producing a sequence of the results.
- [Math.Min Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.min?view=netframework-4.8)

  > Returns the smaller of two numbers.
- [String.Join Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8)

  > Concatenates the elements of a specified array or the members of a
  >   collection, using the specified separator between each element or
  >   member.

Comment: I guess this assumes both arrays are of equal length. Seems implied by the question.

Comment: @RoadRunner yeah, ill make a note about it all the same, thanks